# Solving recurrences $T(n) = 4 T(2n/3) + (n^3 )\cdot \log(n)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a recurrence: $T(n) = 4 \cdot T\left(\frac{2n}{3}\right) + (n^3 )\cdot \log(n)$

how can this case be solved from master theorem as this is not in the general form of 
$T(n) = aT(⌈n/b⌉) + O(nd)$

Comment: I am of the view that this can be solved via master theorem somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that this can be solved via the Master Theorem, though probably not by the version you know. [This version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) of the Master Theorem is more general and states, in part, that if you have a recurrence of the form
$$
T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n)
$$
with $a\ge 1, b>1$ (which we have, since $a=4\ge1$ and $b=(3/2)>1$) then if there is a constant $\epsilon>0$ for which
$$
f(n)=O(n^{\log_b a -\epsilon})
$$
then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$.

To see that this is the case we're interested in, note that $\log_{3/2}4\approx3.419$ so if we can establish that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that
$$
f(n) = n^3\log n = O(n^{\log_b a -\epsilon})
$$
then it will follow that $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_{3/2} 4})$.

I presume you know that $\log n$ grows asymptotically slower than and positive power of $n$, meaning that for any $\alpha >0$ we'll have $\log n=O(n^\alpha)$ so
$$
n^3\log n=O(n^{3+\alpha})
$$
For no particular reason, we'll take $\alpha = 0.4$ then we'll have $n^3\log n=O(n^{3.4})$ and so we'll have
$$
f(n)=O(n^{3.4}) = O(n^{3.419-.019})=O(n^{\log_{3/2} 4-\epsilon})
$$
for $\epsilon\approx 0.019$. The conditions of this case of the Master Theorem are satisfied, so 
$$
T(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_{3/2}4})
$$

Answer (score 0):

Try the substitution $n=(\frac{3}{2})^{u}$

Comment: i am a beginner and do not know how to solve by substitution.I just read the master theorem for solving recurrences. Can yo just outline as how to proceed.

Comment: Perhaps this is not a problem for a beginner?